# Convertir variable a Codigo de barras

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Tengo una cuestion, resulta que debo tomar de un campo el valor respectivo de lo que hay en el mismo.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Documento:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
           <input type="tel" name="" ng-model="documentoIdentidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Documento" id="inputCA">
        </div>
     </div>
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, lo capturo de esta forma, con el model.

```
<td><center><b>{{documentoIdentidad}}</b></center></td>
```

Pero necesito convertir este numero a codigo de barras(hice esto con la libreria de JQuery)

> http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-barcode-last.min.js

Espacio para retornar el codigo:

```
<td colspan="3"><center><div id="bcTarget" ></div></center></td>
```

Con la siguiente funcion obtengo el ID del div.

```
$("#bcTarget").barcode("1234567890", "code128");
```

Pero lo que realmente necesito es pasarle el parametro y/o variable de documento de identidad a la funcion barcode.

Agradezco por llegar hasta aqui y tomarse el tiempo de responder.

Comment: Estoy intentando resolver tu pregunta... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
/*
 *  BarCode Coder Library (BCC Library)
 *  BCCL Version 2.0
 *    
 *  Porting : jQuery barcode plugin 
 *  Version : 2.0.2
 *   
 *  Date  : March 01, 2011
 *  Author  : DEMONTE Jean-Baptiste <jbdemonte@gmail.com>
 *            HOUREZ Jonathan
 *             
 *  Web site: http://barcode-coder.com/
 *  dual licence :  http://www.cecill.info/licences/Licence_CeCILL_V2-fr.html
 *                  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */ 
(function(b){var a={settings:{barWidth:1,barHeight:50,moduleSize:5,showHRI:true,addQuietZone:true,marginHRI:5,bgColor:"#FFFFFF",color:"#000000",fontSize:10,output:"css",posX:0,posY:0},intval:function(d){var c=typeof(d);if(c=="string"){d=d.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g,"");d=parseInt(d*1,10);return isNaN(d)||!isFinite(d)?0:d}return c=="number"&&isFinite(d)?Math.floor(d):0},i25:{encoding:["NNWWN","WNNNW","NWNNW","WWNNN","NNWNW","WNWNN","NWWNN","NNNWW","WNNWN","NWNWN"],compute:function(g,j,f){if(!j){if(g.length%2!=0){g="0"+g}}else{if((f=="int25")&&(g.length%2==0)){g="0"+g}var h=true,c,e=0;for(var d=g.length-1;d>-1;d--){c=a.intval(g.charAt(d));if(isNaN(c)){return("")}e+=h?3*c:c;h=!h}g+=((10-e%10)%10).toString()}return(g)},getDigit:function(k,l,h){k=this.compute(k,l,h);if(k==""){return("")}result="";var f,d;if(h=="int25"){result+="1010";var g,e;for(f=0;f<k.length/2;f++){g=k.charAt(2*f);e=k.charAt(2*f+1);for(d=0;d<5;d++){result+="1";if(this.encoding[g].charAt(d)=="W"){result+="1"}result+="0";if(this.encoding[e].charAt(d)=="W"){result+="0"}}}result+="1101"}else{if(h=="std25"){result+="11011010";var m;for(f=0;f<k.length;f++){m=k.charAt(f);for(d=0;d<5;d++){result+="1";if(this.encoding[m].charAt(d)=="W"){result+="11"}result+="0"}}result+="11010110"}}return(result)}},ean:{encoding:[["0001101","0100111","1110010"],["0011001","0110011","1100110"],["0010011","0011011","1101100"],["0111101","0100001","1000010"],["0100011","0011101","1011100"],["0110001","0111001","1001110"],["0101111","0000101","1010000"],["0111011","0010001","1000100"],["0110111","0001001","1001000"],["0001011","0010111","1110100"]],first:["000000","001011","001101","001110","010011","011001","011100","010101","010110","011010"],getDigit:function(h,g){var d=g=="ean8"?7:12;h=h.substring(0,d);if(h.length!=d){return("")}var k;for(var f=0;f<h.length;f++){k=h.charAt(f);if((k<"0")||(k>"9")){return("")}}h=this.compute(h,g);var j="101";if(g=="ean8"){for(var f=0;f<4;f++){j+=this.encoding[a.intval(h.charAt(f))][0]}j+="01010";for(var f=4;f<8;f++){j+=this.encoding[a.intval(h.charAt(f))][2]}}else{var e=this.first[a.intval(h.charAt(0))];for(var f=1;f<7;f++){j+=this.encoding[a.intval(h.charAt(f))][a.intval(e.charAt(f-1))]}j+="01010";for(var f=7;f<13;f++){j+=this.encoding[a.intval(h.charAt(f))][2]}}j+="101";return(j)},compute:function(f,e){var c=e=="ean13"?12:7;f=f.substring(0,c);var d=0,g=true;for(i=f.length-1;i>-1;i--){d+=(g?3:1)*a.intval(f.charAt(i));g=!g}return(f+((10-d%10)%10).toString())}},msi:{encoding:["100100100100","100100100110","100100110100","100100110110","100110100100","100110100110","100110110100","100110110110","110100100100","110100100110"],compute:function(c,d){if(typeof(d)=="object"){if(d.crc1=="mod10"){c=this.computeMod10(c)}else{if(d.crc1=="mod11"){c=this.computeMod11(c)}}if(d.crc2=="mod10"){c=this.computeMod10(c)}else{if(d.crc2=="mod11"){c=this.computeMod11(c)}}}else{if(typeof(d)=="boolean"){if(d){c=this.computeMod10(c)}}}return(c)},computeMod10:function(h){var d,g=h.length%2;var f=0,e=0;for(d=0;d<h.length;d++){if(g){f=10*f+a.intval(h.charAt(d))}else{e+=a.intval(h.charAt(d))}g=!g}var c=(2*f).toString();for(d=0;d<c.length;d++){e+=a.intval(c.charAt(d))}return(h+((10-e%10)%10).toString())},computeMod11:function(f){var e=0,c=2;for(var d=f.length-1;d>=0;d--){e+=c*a.intval(f.charAt(d));c=c==7?2:c+1}return(f+((11-e%11)%11).toString())},getDigit:function(e,g){var d="0123456789";var c=0;var f="";e=this.compute(e,false);f="110";for(i=0;i<e.length;i++){c=d.indexOf(e.charAt(i));if(c<0){return("")}f+=this.encoding[c]}f+="1001";return(f)}},code11:{encoding:["101011","1101011","1001011","1100101","1011011","1101101","1001101","1010011","1101001","110101","101101"],getDigit:function(d){var q="0123456789-";var g,l,o="",h="0";o="1011001"+h;for(g=0;g<d.length;g++){l=q.indexOf(d.charAt(g));if(l<0){return("")}o+=this.encoding[l]+h}var p=0,e=0,j=1,m=0;for(g=d.length-1;g>=0;g--){p=p==10?1:p+1;j=j==10?1:j+1;l=q.indexOf(d.charAt(g));e+=p*l;m+=j*l}var n=e%11;m+=n;var f=m%11;o+=this.encoding[n]+h;if(d.length>=10){o+=this.encoding[f]+h}o+="1011001";return(o)}},code39:{encoding:["101001101101","110100101011","101100101011","110110010101","101001101011","110100110101","101100110101","101001011011","110100101101","101100101101","110101001011","101101001011","110110100101","101011001011","110101100101","101101100101","101010011011","110101001101","101101001101","101011001101","110101010011","101101010011","110110101001","101011010011","110101101001","101101101001","101010110011","110101011001","101101011001","101011011001","110010101011","100110101011","110011010101","100101101011","110010110101","100110110101","100101011011","110010101101","100110101101","100100100101","100100101001","100101001001","101001001001","100101101101"],getDigit:function(f){var e="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-. $/+%*";var d,c,h="",g="0";if(f.indexOf("*")>=0){return("")}f=("*"+f+"*").toUpperCase();for(d=0;d<f.length;d++){c=e.indexOf(f.charAt(d));if(c<0){return("")}if(d>0){h+=g}h+=this.encoding[c]}return(h)}},code93:{encoding:["100010100","101001000","101000100","101000010","100101000","100100100","100100010","101010000","100010010","100001010","110101000","110100100","110100010","110010100","110010010","110001010","101101000","101100100","101100010","100110100","100011010","101011000","101001100","101000110","100101100","100010110","110110100","110110010","110101100","110100110","110010110","110011010","101101100","101100110","100110110","100111010","100101110","111010100","111010010","111001010","101101110","101110110","110101110","100100110","111011010","111010110","100110010","101011110"],getDigit:function(d,h){var o="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-. $/+%____*",l,m="";if(d.indexOf("*")>=0){return("")}d=d.toUpperCase();m+=this.encoding[47];for(i=0;i<d.length;i++){l=d.charAt(i);index=o.indexOf(l);if((l=="_")||(index<0)){return("")}m+=this.encoding[index]}if(h){var n=0,e=0,g=1,j=0;for(i=d.length-1;i>=0;i--){n=n==20?1:n+1;g=g==15?1:g+1;index=o.indexOf(d.charAt(i));e+=n*index;j+=g*index}var l=e%47;j+=l;var f=j%47;m+=this.encoding[l];m+=this.encoding[f]}m+=this.encoding[47];m+="1";return(m)}},code128:{encoding:["11011001100","11001101100","11001100110","10010011000","10010001100","10001001100","10011001000","10011000100","10001100100","11001001000","11001000100","11000100100","10110011100","10011011100","10011001110","10111001100","10011101100","10011100110","11001110010","11001011100","11001001110","11011100100","11001110100","11101101110","11101001100","11100101100","11100100110","11101100100","11100110100","11100110010","11011011000","11011000110","11000110110","10100011000","10001011000","10001000110","10110001000","10001101000","10001100010","11010001000","11000101000","11000100010","10110111000","10110001110","10001101110","10111011000","10111000110","10001110110","11101110110","11010001110","11000101110","11011101000","11011100010","11011101110","11101011000","11101000110","11100010110","11101101000","11101100010","11100011010","11101111010","11001000010","11110001010","10100110000","10100001100","10010110000","10010000110","10000101100","10000100110","10110010000","10110000100","10011010000","10011000010","10000110100","10000110010","11000010010","11001010000","11110111010","11000010100","10001111010","10100111100","10010111100","10010011110","10111100100","10011110100","10011110010","11110100100","11110010100","11110010010","11011011110","11011110110","11110110110","10101111000","10100011110","10001011110","10111101000","10111100010","11110101000","11110100010","10111011110","10111101110","11101011110","11110101110","11010000100","11010010000","11010011100","11000111010"],getDigit:function(d){var m=" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";var n="";var k=0;var e=0;var h=0;var g=0;var o=0;for(h=0;h<d.length;h++){if(m.indexOf(d.charAt(h))==-1){return("")}}var f=d.length>1;var l="";for(h=0;h<3&&h<d.length;h++){l=d.charAt(h);f&=l>="0"&&l<="9"}k=f?105:104;n=this.encoding[k];h=0;while(h<d.length){if(!f){g=0;while((h+g<d.length)&&(d.charAt(h+g)>="0")&&(d.charAt(h+g)<="9")){g++}f=(g>5)||((h+g-1==d.length)&&(g>3));if(f){n+=this.encoding[99];k+=++e*99}}else{if((h==d.length)||(d.charAt(h)<"0")||(d.charAt(h)>"9")||(d.charAt(h+1)<"0")||(d.charAt(h+1)>"9")){f=false;n+=this.encoding[100];k+=++e*100}}if(f){o=a.intval(d.charAt(h)+d.charAt(h+1));h+=2}else{o=m.indexOf(d.charAt(h));h+=1}n+=this.encoding[o];k+=++e*o}n+=this.encoding[k%103];n+=this.encoding[106];n+="11";return(n)}},codabar:{encoding:["101010011","101011001","101001011","110010101","101101001","110101001","100101011","100101101","100110101","110100101","101001101","101100101","1101011011","1101101011","1101101101","1011011011","1011001001","1010010011","1001001011","1010011001"],getDigit:function(f){var e="0123456789-$:/.+";var d,c,h="",g="0";h+=this.encoding[16]+g;for(d=0;d<f.length;d++){c=e.indexOf(f.charAt(d));if(c<0){return("")}h+=this.encoding[c]+g}h+=this.encoding[16];return(h)}},datamatrix:{encoding:["101010011","101011001","101001011","110010101","101101001","110101001","100101011","100101101","100110101","110100101","101001101","101100101","1101011011","1101101011","1101101101","1011011011","1011001001","1010010011","1001001011","1010011001"],lengthRows:[10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,32,36,40,44,48,52,64,72,80,88,96,104,120,132,144,8,8,12,12,16,16],lengthCols:[10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,32,36,40,44,48,52,64,72,80,88,96,104,120,132,144,18,32,26,36,36,48],mappingRows:[8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,56,64,72,80,88,96,108,120,132,6,6,10,10,14,14],mappingCols:[8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,56,64,72,80,88,96,108,120,132,16,28,24,32,32,44],dataCWCount:[3,5,8,12,18,22,30,36,44,62,86,114,144,174,204,280,368,456,576,696,816,1050,1304,1558,5,10,16,22,32,49],solomonCWCount:[5,7,10,12,14,18,20,24,28,36,42,48,56,68,84,112,144,192,224,272,336,408,496,620,7,11,14,18,24,28],dataRegionRows:[8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,14,16,18,20,22,24,14,16,18,20,22,24,18,20,22,6,6,10,10,14,14],dataRegionCols:[8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,14,16,18,20,22,24,14,16,18,20,22,24,18,20,22,16,14,24,16,16,22],regionRows:[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,1],regionCols:[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,1,2,1,2,2,2],interleavedBlocks:[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,8,8,1,1,1,1,1,1],logTab:[-255,255,1,240,2,225,241,53,3,38,226,133,242,43,54,210,4,195,39,114,227,106,134,28,243,140,44,23,55,118,211,234,5,219,196,96,40,222,115,103,228,78,107,125,135,8,29,162,244,186,141,180,45,99,24,49,56,13,119,153,212,199,235,91,6,76,220,217,197,11,97,184,41,36,223,253,116,138,104,193,229,86,79,171,108,165,126,145,136,34,9,74,30,32,163,84,245,173,187,204,142,81,181,190,46,88,100,159,25,231,50,207,57,147,14,67,120,128,154,248,213,167,200,63,236,110,92,176,7,161,77,124,221,102,218,95,198,90,12,152,98,48,185,179,42,209,37,132,224,52,254,239,117,233,139,22,105,27,194,113,230,206,87,158,80,189,172,203,109,175,166,62,127,247,146,66,137,192,35,252,10,183,75,216,31,83,33,73,164,144,85,170,246,65,174,61,188,202,205,157,143,169,82,72,182,215,191,251,47,178,89,151,101,94,160,123,26,112,232,21,51,238,208,131,58,69,148,18,15,16,68,17,121,149,129,19,155,59,249,70,214,250,168,71,201,156,64,60,237,130,111,20,93,122,177,150],aLogTab:[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,45,90,180,69,138,57,114,228,229,231,227,235,251,219,155,27,54,108,216,157,23,46,92,184,93,186,89,178,73,146,9,18,36,72,144,13,26,52,104,208,141,55,110,220,149,7,14,28,56,112,224,237,247,195,171,123,246,193,175,115,230,225,239,243,203,187,91,182,65,130,41,82,164,101,202,185,95,190,81,162,105,210,137,63,126,252,213,135,35,70,140,53,106,212,133,39,78,156,21,42,84,168,125,250,217,159,19,38,76,152,29,58,116,232,253,215,131,43,86,172,117,234,249,223,147,11,22,44,88,176,77,154,25,50,100,200,189,87,174,113,226,233,255,211,139,59,118,236,245,199,163,107,214,129,47,94,188,85,170,121,242,201,191,83,166,97,194,169,127,254,209,143,51,102,204,181,71,142,49,98,196,165,103,206,177,79,158,17,34,68,136,61,122,244,197,167,99,198,161,111,222,145,15,30,60,120,240,205,183,67,134,33,66,132,37,74,148,5,10,20,40,80,160,109,218,153,31,62,124,248,221,151,3,6,12,24,48,96,192,173,119,238,241,207,179,75,150,1],champGaloisMult:function(d,c){if(!d||!c){return 0}return this.aLogTab[(this.logTab[d]+this.logTab[c])%255]},champGaloisDoub:function(d,c){if(!d){return 0}if(!c){return d}return this.aLogTab[(this.logTab[d]+c)%255]},champGaloisSum:function(d,c){return d^c},selectIndex:function(c,d){if((c<1||c>1558)&&!d){return -1}if((c<1||c>49)&&d){return -1}var e=0;if(d){e=24}while(this.dataCWCount[e]<c){e++}return e},encodeDataCodeWordsASCII:function(f){var e=new Array();var h=0,d,g;for(d=0;d<f.length;d++){g=f.charCodeAt(d);if(g>127){e[h]=235;g=g-127;h++}else{if((g>=48&&g<=57)&&(d+1<f.length)&&(f.charCodeAt(d+1)>=48&&f.charCodeAt(d+1)<=57)){g=((g-48)*10)+((f.charCodeAt(d+1))-48);g+=130;d++}else{g++}}e[h]=g;h++}return e},addPadCW:function(d,g,f){if(g>=f){return}d[g]=129;var e,c;for(c=g+1;c<f;c++){e=((149*(c+1))%253)+1;d[c]=(129+e)%254}},calculSolFactorTable:function(c){var f=new Array();var e,d;for(e=0;e<=c;e++){f[e]=1}for(e=1;e<=c;e++){for(d=e-1;d>=0;d--){f[d]=this.champGaloisDoub(f[d],e);if(d>0){f[d]=this.champGaloisSum(f[d],f[d-1])}}}return f},addReedSolomonCW:function(c,g,l,m,h){var o=0;var n=c/h;var p=new Array();var f,e,d;for(d=0;d<h;d++){for(f=0;f<n;f++){p[f]=0}for(f=d;f<l;f=f+h){o=this.champGaloisSum(m[f],p[n-1]);for(e=n-1;e>=0;e--){if(!o){p[e]=0}else{p[e]=this.champGaloisMult(o,g[e])}if(e>0){p[e]=this.champGaloisSum(p[e-1],p[e])}}}e=l+d;for(f=n-1;f>=0;f--){m[e]=p[f];e=e+h}}return m},getBits:function(d){var e=new Array();for(var c=0;c<8;c++){e[c]=d&(128>>c)?1:0}return e},next:function(h,k,d,j,g,c){var f=0;var l=4;var e=0;do{if((l==k)&&(e==0)){this.patternShapeSpecial1(g,c,j[f],k,d);f++}else{if((h<3)&&(l==k-2)&&(e==0)&&(d%4!=0)){this.patternShapeSpecial2(g,c,j[f],k,d);f++}else{if((l==k-2)&&(e==0)&&(d%8==4)){this.patternShapeSpecial3(g,c,j[f],k,d);f++}else{if((l==k+4)&&(e==2)&&(d%8==0)){this.patternShapeSpecial4(g,c,j[f],k,d);f++}}}}do{if((l<k)&&(e>=0)&&(c[l][e]!=1)){this.patternShapeStandard(g,c,j[f],l,e,k,d);f++}l-=2;e+=2}while((l>=0)&&(e<d));l+=1;e+=3;do{if((l>=0)&&(e<d)&&(c[l][e]!=1)){this.patternShapeStandard(g,c,j[f],l,e,k,d);f++}l+=2;e-=2}while((l<k)&&(e>=0));l+=3;e+=1}while((l<k)||(e<d))},patternShapeStandard:function(g,f,h,j,e,d,c){this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[0],j-2,e-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[1],j-2,e-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[2],j-1,e-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[3],j-1,e-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[4],j-1,e,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[5],j,e-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[6],j,e-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(g,f,h[7],j,e,d,c)},patternShapeSpecial1:function(f,e,g,d,c){this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[0],d-1,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[1],d-1,1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[2],d-1,2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[3],0,c-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[4],0,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[5],1,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[6],2,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[7],3,c-1,d,c)},patternShapeSpecial2:function(f,e,g,d,c){this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[0],d-3,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[1],d-2,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[2],d-1,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[3],0,c-4,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[4],0,c-3,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[5],0,c-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[6],0,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[7],1,c-1,d,c)},patternShapeSpecial3:function(f,e,g,d,c){this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[0],d-3,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[1],d-2,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[2],d-1,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[3],0,c-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[4],0,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[5],1,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[6],2,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[7],3,c-1,d,c)},patternShapeSpecial4:function(f,e,g,d,c){this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[0],d-1,0,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[1],d-1,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[2],0,c-3,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[3],0,c-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[4],0,c-1,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[5],1,c-3,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[6],1,c-2,d,c);this.placeBitInDatamatrix(f,e,g[7],1,c-1,d,c)},placeBitInDatamatrix:function(g,f,j,h,e,d,c){if(h<0){h+=d;e+=4-((d+4)%8)}if(e<0){e+=c;h+=4-((c+4)%8)}if(f[h][e]!=1){g[h][e]=j;f[h][e]=1}},addFinderPattern:function(h,m,d,n,c){var l=(n+2)*m;var k=(c+2)*d;var e=new Array();e[0]=new Array();for(var f=0;f<k+2;f++){e[0][f]=0}for(var g=0;g<l;g++){e[g+1]=new Array();e[g+1][0]=0;e[g+1][k+1]=0;for(var f=0;f<k;f++){if(g%(n+2)==0){if(f%2==0){e[g+1][f+1]=1}else{e[g+1][f+1]=0}}else{if(g%(n+2)==n+1){e[g+1][f+1]=1}else{if(f%(c+2)==c+1){if(g%2==0){e[g+1][f+1]=0}else{e[g+1][f+1]=1}}else{if(f%(c+2)==0){e[g+1][f+1]=1}else{e[g+1][f+1]=0;e[g+1][f+1]=h[g-1-(2*(parseInt(g/(n+2))))][f-1-(2*(parseInt(f/(c+2))))]}}}}}}e[l+1]=new Array();for(var f=0;f<k+2;f++){e[l+1][f]=0}return e},getDigit:function(m,u){var s=this.encodeDataCodeWordsASCII(m);var e=s.length;var h=this.selectIndex(e,u);var n=this.dataCWCount[h];var x=this.solomonCWCount[h];var c=n+x;var A=this.lengthRows[h];var z=this.lengthCols[h];var k=this.regionRows[h];var l=this.regionCols[h];var f=this.dataRegionRows[h];var y=this.dataRegionCols[h];var w=A-2*k;var j=z-2*l;var p=this.interleavedBlocks[h];var q=(x/p);var d=(n/p);this.addPadCW(s,e,n);var v=this.calculSolFactorTable(q);this.addReedSolomonCW(x,v,n,s,p);var t=new Array();for(var r=0;r<c;r++){t[r]=this.getBits(s[r])}var B=new Array();var o=new Array();for(var r=0;r<j;r++){B[r]=new Array();o[r]=new Array()}if(((w*j)%8)==4){B[w-2][j-2]=1;B[w-1][j-1]=1;B[w-1][j-2]=0;B[w-2][j-1]=0;o[w-2][j-2]=1;o[w-1][j-1]=1;o[w-1][j-2]=1;o[w-2][j-1]=1}this.next(0,w,j,t,B,o);B=this.addFinderPattern(B,k,l,f,y);return B}},lec:{cInt:function(e,f){var d="";for(var c=0;c<f;c++){d+=String.fromCharCode(e&255);e=e>>8}return d},cRgb:function(e,d,c){return String.fromCharCode(c)+String.fromCharCode(d)+String.fromCharCode(e)},cHexColor:function(h){var d=parseInt("0x"+h.substr(1));var c=d&255;d=d>>8;var f=d&255;var e=d>>8;return(this.cRgb(e,f,c))}},hexToRGB:function(h){var d=parseInt("0x"+h.substr(1));var c=d&255;d=d>>8;var f=d&255;var e=d>>8;return({r:e,g:f,b:c})},isHexColor:function(d){var c=new RegExp("#[0-91-F]","gi");return d.match(c)},base64Encode:function(o){var c="",h,f,e,n,m,l,j;var d="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";var g=0;while(g<o.length){h=o.charCodeAt(g++);f=o.charCodeAt(g++);e=o.charCodeAt(g++);n=h>>2;m=((h&3)<<4)|(f>>4);l=((f&15)<<2)|(e>>6);j=e&63;if(isNaN(f)){l=j=64}else{if(isNaN(e)){j=64}}c+=d.charAt(n)+d.charAt(m)+d.charAt(l)+d.charAt(j)}return c},bitStringTo2DArray:function(f){var e=[];e[0]=[];for(var c=0;c<f.length;c++){e[0][c]=f.charAt(c)}return(e)},resize:function(d,c){d.css("padding","0px").css("overflow","auto").css("width",c+"px").html("");return d},digitToBmpRenderer:function(t,w,o,g,n,z){var e=o.length;var f=o[0].length;var u=0;var r=this.isHexColor(w.bgColor)?this.lec.cHexColor(w.bgColor):this.lec.cRgb(255,255,255);var q=this.isHexColor(w.color)?this.lec.cHexColor(w.color):this.lec.cRgb(0,0,0);var d="";var c="";for(u=0;u<n;u++){d+=r;c+=q}var p="";var C=(4-((n*f*3)%4))%4;var B=(n*f+C)*z*e;var v="";for(u=0;u<C;u++){v+="\0"}var A="BM"+this.lec.cInt(54+B,4)+"\0\0\0\0"+this.lec.cInt(54,4)+this.lec.cInt(40,4)+this.lec.cInt(n*f,4)+this.lec.cInt(z*e,4)+this.lec.cInt(1,2)+this.lec.cInt(24,2)+"\0\0\0\0"+this.lec.cInt(B,4)+this.lec.cInt(2835,4)+this.lec.cInt(2835,4)+this.lec.cInt(0,4)+this.lec.cInt(0,4);for(var h=e-1;h>=0;h--){var l="";for(var j=0;j<f;j++){l+=o[h][j]=="0"?d:c}l+=v;for(var s=0;s<z;s++){A+=l}}var m=document.createElement("object");m.setAttribute("type","image/bmp");m.setAttribute("data","data:image/bmp;base64,"+this.base64Encode(A));this.resize(t,n*f+C).append(m)},digitToBmp:function(g,f,j,d){var c=a.intval(f.barWidth);var e=a.intval(f.barHeight);this.digitToBmpRenderer(g,f,this.bitStringTo2DArray(j),d,c,e)},digitToBmp2D:function(f,e,g,c){var d=a.intval(e.moduleSize);this.digitToBmpRenderer(f,e,g,c,d,d)},digitToCssRenderer:function(q,d,m,e,p,g){var r=m.length;var c=m[0].length;var j="";var o='<div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: '+d.bgColor+"; height: "+g+'px; width: &Wpx"></div>';var l='<div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: &Wpx solid '+d.color+"; height: "+g+'px;"></div>';var f,h;for(var k=0;k<r;k++){f=0;h=m[k][0];for(var n=0;n<c;n++){if(h==m[k][n]){f++}else{j+=(h=="0"?o:l).replace("&W",f*p);h=m[k][n];f=1}}if(f>0){j+=(h=="0"?o:l).replace("&W",f*p)}}if(d.showHRI){j+='<div style="clear:both; width: 100%; background-color: '+d.bgColor+"; color: "+d.color+"; text-align: center; font-size: "+d.fontSize+"px; margin-top: "+d.marginHRI+'px;">'+e+"</div>"}this.resize(q,p*c).html(j)},digitToCss:function(g,f,j,d){var c=a.intval(f.barWidth);var e=a.intval(f.barHeight);this.digitToCssRenderer(g,f,this.bitStringTo2DArray(j),d,c,e)},digitToCss2D:function(f,e,g,c){var d=a.intval(e.moduleSize);this.digitToCssRenderer(f,e,g,c,d,d)},digitToSvgRenderer:function(q,s,n,f,l,t){var d=n.length;var e=n[0].length;var o=l*e;var u=t*d;if(s.showHRI){var g=a.intval(s.fontSize);u+=a.intval(s.marginHRI)+g}var m='<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="'+o+'" height="'+u+'">';m+='<rect width="'+o+'" height="'+u+'" x="0" y="0" fill="'+s.bgColor+'" />';var c='<rect width="&W" height="'+t+'" x="&X" y="&Y" fill="'+s.color+'" />';var r,p;for(var h=0;h<d;h++){r=0;p=n[h][0];for(var j=0;j<e;j++){if(p==n[h][j]){r++}else{if(p=="1"){m+=c.replace("&W",r*l).replace("&X",(j-r)*l).replace("&Y",h*t)}p=n[h][j];r=1}}if((r>0)&&(p=="1")){m+=c.replace("&W",r*l).replace("&X",(e-r)*l).replace("&Y",h*t)}}if(s.showHRI){m+='<g transform="translate('+Math.floor(o/2)+' 0)">';m+='<text y="'+(u-Math.floor(g/2))+'" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: '+g+'px;" fill="'+s.color+'">'+f+"</text>";m+="</g>"}m+="</svg>";var k=document.createElement("object");k.setAttribute("type","image/svg+xml");k.setAttribute("data","data:image/svg+xml,"+m);this.resize(q,o).append(k)},digitToSvg:function(g,f,j,d){var c=a.intval(f.barWidth);var e=a.intval(f.barHeight);this.digitToSvgRenderer(g,f,this.bitStringTo2DArray(j),d,c,e)},digitToSvg2D:function(f,e,g,c){var d=a.intval(e.moduleSize);this.digitToSvgRenderer(f,e,g,c,d,d)},digitToCanvasRenderer:function(s,d,o,f,m,e,q,k){var j=s.get(0);if(!j||!j.getContext){return}var t=o.length;var c=o[0].length;var r=j.getContext("2d");r.lineWidth=1;r.lineCap="butt";r.fillStyle=d.bgColor;r.fillRect(m,e,c*q,t*k);r.fillStyle=d.color;for(var n=0;n<t;n++){var h=0;var l=o[n][0];for(var p=0;p<c;p++){if(l==o[n][p]){h++}else{if(l=="1"){r.fillRect(m+(p-h)*q,e+n*k,q*h,k)}l=o[n][p];h=1}}if((h>0)&&(l=="1")){r.fillRect(m+(c-h)*q,e+n*k,q*h,k)}}if(d.showHRI){var g=r.measureText(f);r.fillText(f,m+Math.floor((c*q-g.width)/2),e+t*k+d.fontSize+d.marginHRI)}},digitToCanvas:function(j,g,l,e){var d=a.intval(g.barWidth);var f=a.intval(g.barHeight);var c=a.intval(g.posX);var k=a.intval(g.posY);this.digitToCanvasRenderer(j,g,this.bitStringTo2DArray(l),e,c,k,d,f)},digitToCanvas2D:function(g,f,j,d){var e=a.intval(f.moduleSize);var c=a.intval(f.posX);var h=a.intval(f.posY);this.digitToCanvasRenderer(g,f,j,d,c,h,e,e)}};b.fn.extend({barcode:function(h,m,f){var o="",g="",d="",k=true,n=false,j=false;if(typeof(h)=="string"){d=h}else{if(typeof(h)=="object"){d=typeof(h.code)=="string"?h.code:"";k=typeof(h.crc)!="undefined"?h.crc:true;n=typeof(h.rect)!="undefined"?h.rect:false}}if(d==""){return(false)}if(typeof(f)=="undefined"){f=[]}for(var c in a.settings){if(f[c]==undefined){f[c]=a.settings[c]}}switch(m){case"std25":case"int25":o=a.i25.getDigit(d,k,m);g=a.i25.compute(d,k,m);break;case"ean8":case"ean13":o=a.ean.getDigit(d,m);g=a.ean.compute(d,m);break;case"code11":o=a.code11.getDigit(d);g=d;break;case"code39":o=a.code39.getDigit(d);g=d;break;case"code93":o=a.code93.getDigit(d,k);g=d;break;case"code128":o=a.code128.getDigit(d);g=d;break;case"codabar":o=a.codabar.getDigit(d);g=d;break;case"msi":o=a.msi.getDigit(d,k);g=a.msi.compute(d,k);break;case"datamatrix":o=a.datamatrix.getDigit(d,n);g=d;j=true;break}if(o.length==0){return(b(this))}if(!j&&f.addQuietZone){o="0000000000"+o+"0000000000"}var l=b(this);var e="digitTo"+f.output.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+f.output.substr(1)+(j?"2D":"");if(typeof(a[e])=="function"){a[e](l,f,o,g)}return(l)}})}(jQuery));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Documento:</label>
        <span ng-bind="documentoIdentidad"></span>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
           <input type="tel" name="" ng-model="documentoIdentidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Documento" id="inputCA" ng-change="algo()">
           <div id="bcTarget"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.algo = function() {
          $("#bcTarget").barcode($scope.documentoIdentidad, "code128");
        };
      });

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si esto es lo que buscas espero que te pueda servir. Saludos si alguna cosa me cuentas.

Comment: Excelente aporte, era lo que necesitaba!

Comment: Con mucho gusto amigo, para ayudar estamos :)

Comment: Asi es, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recuperar el valor que hay en el input e introducirlo en la función de barcode:

```
$("#bcTarget").barcode($('#inputCA').val(), "code128");
```

Comment: Tambien es funcional lo que mencionas, muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo!